# IE7 rollover not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, rollover

I have some code which is working fine in IE8, FF & Safari on a PC, but not in IE7. The idea is to have a large button, with a background image in the  tag, and text & a foreground image. When the user rolls over the button, the background image is replaced with a different one:

CSS:

```
ul { list-style-type:none; }

ul li { display:inline; }

ul li.link a {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    background:url(templatebtn.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:294px;
    height:250px;
    display:block;
    padding:6px 0 0 6px;
    }

ul li.link a:hover {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    background:url(templatebtnover.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:294px;
    height:250px;
    display:block;
    padding:6px 0 0 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="link">
<a id="button1" class="btn">
<div class="btntitle"><p><strong>A title</strong></p></div>
<div class="btnpic"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

In IE7, the image is not replaced on hover, and the cursor doesn't change to a pointer. Even if I remove most of the gunk from the css a:hover, and just have a:hover { cursor:pointer; } it still doesn't work (i.e. the cursor doesn't change). I've googled this for an age & must be missing something obvious... And ideas?

Thanks,
G

Comment: `div` is not allowed inside `a` in XHTML and HTML <5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `div` to `span`. XHTML and HTML <5 do not allow `div` inside `a`.

Edit: Oh and while you are at it, remove the `p`, because `p` inside `span` is not allowed. :)

Edit 2: Add a `href` attribute to the `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. However this is still not working. I changed <div>s to <span>s and removed the <p>, the rollover is still not responding.

Comment: Give your `a` a `href` attribute.  `<a href="#" `  Here is a jsfiddle that reproduces your error http://jsfiddle.net/ZpAjt/1/ Try removing the `href` attribute to see the difference (in IE7)

Comment: The `href` is the critical part. I was going to post an answer explaining, but you got there just in time :P (+1)

Comment: haha lucky me :) I only noticed it missing when I was trying to reproduce the error with JSfiddle. I do know `a` renders similar to `span` when the `href` is omitted but when it's not there you don't always see the error at first glance. :)

Comment: Gah! I'm kicking myself. Thanks guys, that fixes it. Appreciate your help.